# add @media CSS properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

in React I can add css property with js.

```
ref.current.style.background = 'red'
or
ref.current.style = {background:'red'}
```

Is it possible to add @media ?

I know that it is possible to track the screen size in js, but I want to add this css property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this using window.matchMedia - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp;

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) {
    ref.current.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add @media property to style?

Comment: No, the only way to do it is using @media in the css file and attaching the class to your desired component, or using window.matchMedia and conditionally adding the class there.